# Jackson different mixins for same class

Tags: java, json, jackson, pojo

I want to use different mixins for the same class during a serialize process. For example I want to seralize this pojo:

```
private Rectangle rect1;
private Rectangle rect2;
```

Now I want to use Mixin1 for rect1 and Mixin2 for rect2. I know this way:

```
objectMapper.getSerializationConfig().addMixInAnnotations(Rectangle.class, MixIn.class);
```

but that does not help me. I want different mixins for each property which are the same class.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible; only a single mix-in can be applied per target Class (or interface), and that is static, not dynamic. For different configurations, you would need multiple `ObjectMapper`s.

Maybe you could elaborate on what you are trying to achieve, since this approach will not get you there?